# No Internet Connection

Tags: connection, networking, internet, ping

I'm using a CAT6 cable to connect my RPi 2 to D-Link ADSL Modem.
But I can't!

Here are what I've already tested:

When the system is up, I run:

```
ping google.com
```

it says:

```
ping: unknown host google.com
```

---

Then I type:

```
ping 192.168.1.1
```

it says:

```
connect: Network is unreachable
```

---

Then I type:

```
route
```

or

```
route -n
```

it says:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination    Gateway    Genmask    Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
```

---

Then I type:

```
ifconfig
```

it says:

```
#
```

actually it doesn't say anything!!

---

And here is the content of `/etc/network/interfaces` :

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

# iface eth0 inet static
# address 192.168.1.88
# netmask 255.255.255.0
# gateway 192.168.1.1
# network 192.168.1.0
```

I also uncommented the last lines of this file, so it looked like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.88
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
network 192.168.1.0
```

Then I rebooted the system; but it didn't work!

---

I tested the LAN cable on my laptop; it works fine.

---

By the way, I'm using RPi 2, which has `Minibian` installed on it. Minibian is a minimal version of `Raspbian`.

---

So, what should I do to connect to the internet?

---

---

***Update 1***

Here are some other tests:

I type:

```
lspci | grep Ethernet
```

it says:

```
-bash: lspci: command not found
```

---

I type:

```
ping 127.0.0.1
```

it says:

```
connect: Network is unreachable
```

---

In `/etc/network/interfaces` , I commented the `iface eth0 inet dhcp` , and uncommented the others. But it didn't change anything.

---

I type:

```
ifconfig -a
```

it says:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:7f:c1:5f
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          LOOPBACK MTU:65536 Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

---

---

***Update 2***

Here are some additional tests:

I type:

```
ifconfig lo up
ifconfig eth0 up
```

and then I type:

```
ifconfig
```

it says:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:7f:c1:5f
          inet6 addr: fe80::ba27:ebff:fe7f:c15f/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:556 (556.0 B)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr : ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:65536 Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

Then I type:

```
ping 127.0.0.1
```

and it worked! it sent and received several packages. However, `ping 192.168.1.1` or other pings still don't work.

---

---

***Update 3***

More tests:

I type:

```
ifconfig eth0
```

it says:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:7f:c1:5f
          inet6 addr: fe80::ba27:ebff:fe7f:c15f/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:623 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:6 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:48742 (47.5 KiB)  TX bytes:556 (556.0 B)
```

Comment: Any RX/TX lights on the Pi? (Indicating that it sees the Ethernet cable as active?)  Also if you uncomment the eth0 inet static, you must comment out the eth0 inet dhcp.

Comment: Thanks @Butters for your comment. Yes, the LEDs are blinking on the RPi LAN port.

Comment: try `lspci | grep Ethernet` to see if the system recognizes your Ethernet card.  Also have you tried Rasbian that was compiled for the Pi2?  Personally, I cant think of a reason to have a 'more cutdown' distro of Linux, just run it without a GUI.

Comment: I have tested Raspbian before. The boot time is the main reason I installed Minibian. It boots in max. 15 seconds. I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: the fact that `ifconfig` shows nothing at all is very odd, you'd at least have `lo` ... does `ping 127.0.0.1` work? It's like no networking modules are installed. try `ifconfig -a` - that should show even disabled interfaces

Comment: Dear @Butters, I did what you suggested, and posted the results as ***Update 1*** in the main topic. Any suggestions?

Comment: Dear @JaromandaX , I did what you suggested, and posted the results as ***Update 1*** in the main topic. Any suggestions?

Comment: so the interfaces are present, just disabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems that the `networking` service had to be enabled manually!

So I did:

```
/etc/init.d/networking start
```

And voila! It worked :D

Comment: Glad you got it going.  You should be able to run the command `update-rc.d networking enable` to make it auto start on boot.

Answer (score 1):

try setting your network/interfaces file to

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

after you edit the file, if you're running jessie, you *may* need to run

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

edit:

```
ifconfig lo up
ifconfig eth0 up
ifconfig
```

they should show without the `-a` now

note: this wont **fix** the problem, I just want to see if the interfaces come up (and stay up) when you force them to be up

Something else is bringing them down - output of `dmesg` command bay be useful to see what's happening during boot

after update 3:

change /etc/network/interfaces to

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0

iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.88
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.1.1
network 192.168.1.0
```

Assuming your router is 192.168.1.1

Comment: Thanks @JaromandaX for your answer. I edited the `/etc/network/interfaces` to what you said. But it didn't work. I rebooted the system. It didn't work again. I typed `systemctl daemon-reload` , but it said `bash: command not found` !!

Comment: so you're not running `jessie`

Comment: So, what should I do now?

Comment: I've added something to the answer

Comment: Dear @JaromandaX , I did what you said, and posted the results as ***Update 2*** in the main topic.

Comment: OK now you need to set the ip address of eth0 - seems you don't have a DHCP server (or your system isn't finding one) ... if you type `ifconfig eth0` does it have an `inet` address now?

Comment: There's still the problem of what is bringing the network **DOWN** in the first place - that's unusual behaviour - though, minibian may be doing that deliberately!!

Comment: Dear @JaromandaX , see ***Update 3*** .

Comment: @Omid1989 - see updated answer

Comment: Dear @JaromandaX , I changed `/etc/network/interfaces` , but the problem still remains. It only pings `127.0.0.1` . Other pings are non-responsive! Also, there's another problem: After reboot, I have to type `ifconfig lo up` and `ifconfig eth0 up` to enable `ping 127.0.0.1` !!

Comment: Do you know the IP address of your router? or any other machine on your LAN

Comment: ` After reboot, I have to type` - definitely something is forcing network down on boot

Comment: Dear @JaromandaX , My ADSL Modem's IP is 192.168.1.1, I can access it via my laptop. So, how do I know what forces the network down? `dmesg` gives a lot of responses. How can I narrow it down? `dmesg | grep ethernet` gives nothing.

Comment: Problem solved finally @JaromandaX !! I typed `/etc/init.d/networking start` and it worked !!

Comment: that wont "survive" a reboot - you may need to do an `update-rc.d` - look at the man page, it may be update-rc.d enable networking but I'm not sure

Comment: Actually @JaromandaX , I don't need internet connection on every reboot. I just wanted to install python gpio package. If needed, I can add `/etc/init.d/networking start` to `rc.local` to enable it at every reboot. Thanks anyway for your point on `update-rc.d` .